# SmartGWT Program not displaying getting wnd.isc.Browser is null

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

When running my gwt program in GWT Development Mode it fails to display showing this error in the console:

com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): '$wnd.isc.Browser' is null or not an object

I do not believe the error is due to my project setup. Other member of the team can compile fine. It is most likely some type of config problem on my end. I have re-checked out the project and still get the error.

I am using the latest jdk 1.6.0_19 if that matters

Answer (score 3):

It does not really make sense since your other team members can run the app but to me that sounds like you are using

```
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoScript"/>
```

in your gwt.xml config and some of the smartgwt js files are not loaded. Try to check for that using firebug (network tab)

Comment: It appears that I have [the same issue](http://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a/33416-core-smartclient-javascript-libraries-appear-not-to-be-loaded) but I can't seem to be able to fix it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @StefanFalk you comment on a >5 year old question by linking to a solved issue on some forum? open a new question and provide detail like everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that if you inherit the NoScript module, you need to have an install of smartClient.

```
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoScript"/>
```

On the other hand, if you have no smartClient install, you need to inherit:

```
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt"/>
```

Comment: It appears that I have [the same issue](http://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a/33416-core-smartclient-javascript-libraries-appear-not-to-be-loaded) but I can't seem to be able to fix it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @StefanFalk Sorry no, I did not touch smartgwt since 2010. A long time ago ;)

Comment: Anything else you'd recommend? :D

Comment: You may open an issue on the official smartgwt repository: https://github.com/isomorphic-software/smartgwt/issues

Comment: No,I mean using something else than Smart GWT. I am not so sure if I want to use it anyway :D